# How to await response in client interceptor in Kotlin GRPC

Tags: kotlin, grpc

I would like to wrap all GRPC calls with try/catch on the client side and throw a different exception. The goal is to capture the client side stacktrace, which is usually missing when a non-success status is returned from the server. In fact, the GRPC client re-throws the StatusException returned from the server and doesn't capture the client side stacktrace, which makes it difficult to find out where the failing request originated from.

With dotnet GRPC, I can await the response in a client interceptor as follows (though I am not entirely sure if this works):

```cs
public class ExceptionWrapperInterceptor : Interceptor
{
    public override AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse> AsyncUnaryCall<TRequest, TResponse>(
        TRequest request,
        ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context,
        AsyncUnaryCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {
        var call = continuation(request, context);

        return new AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse>(
            HandleResponse(call.ResponseAsync),
            call.ResponseHeadersAsync,
            call.GetStatus,
            call.GetTrailers,
            call.Dispose);
    }

    private async Task<TResponse> HandleResponse<TResponse>(Task<TResponse> inner)
    {
        try
        {
            return await inner;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApiClientException("GRPC Call Failed", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to do something similar with Kotlin. My end goal is to have a try/catch around every outgoing GRPC call and to throw a custom exception (GrpcClientException) that allows me to capture the full stracktrace.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide more details: example code you use and what is the expected and actual behavior. I don't know gRPC, but I see it is implemented as suspend functions, so the solution should be as simple as: `try { doSomething() } catch (e: SomeException) { throw AnotherException() }`.

Comment: I'd expect you can do something equivalent to the .NET interceptor with just the standard interception API from Java.

Comment: I suppose you can create an interceptor that will return a SimpleForwardingClientCall where `start` is overridden to wrap the listener into SimpleForwardingClientCallListener. Override the `onClose` in the forwarding listener. Not sure if you can raise from there, but maybe add some valuable info to the trailersMetadata which will be included in the StatusException here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-kotlin/blob/253c24f5801446dbe142c7e1b7a1716b841dc238/stub/src/main/java/io/grpc/kotlin/ClientCalls.kt#L295

Comment: @YuriGolobokov I tried several variations of that but couldn't make it work. Even ChatGPT gives several similar answers but none really works.

Comment: What exactly is not working when you try that? Can you show code example and error message?

Comment: The whole approach of try/catch around onClose doesn't work, the exception is not thrown there. If you have a solution in mind maybe you can try it and post a response if it works?